# How to display multiple text lines before user inputs any text for console app

Tags: c#

In my C# console application i would like to display multiple lines of text before user enters any input like below:

```
Username:
Password:
```

with the cursor next to username.

Calling `Console.ReadLine()` in between the two `Write()` function only displays the password line once user input has been entered for username.

I also have to try and keep it from messing with the code that displays the password as * while typing.

Any help would be much appreciated. I've provided code for the whole method though it's unlikely the bottom part is useful.

```cs
public void mainMenu()
{  
    String userNameLbl = "Username:";
    String pWordLbl = "Password:";

    Console.Write(
        String.Format(
           "{0," + ((Console.WindowWidth / 4) + userNameLbl.Length - 3) + "}", 
           userNameLbl));

    userName = Console.ReadLine();

    Console.Write(
         String.Format(
             "{0," + ((Console.WindowWidth / 4) + pWordLbl.Length - 3) + "}",
             pWordLbl));

    //password appears as *
    do
    {
        ConsoleKeyInfo key = Console.ReadKey(true);
        // as long as key is not backspace or enter
        if (key.Key != ConsoleKey.Backspace && key.Key != ConsoleKey.Enter)
        {
            // add character to passWord and print '*'
            passWord += key.KeyChar;
            Console.Write("*");
        }
        else
        {
            // backspacing
            if (key.Key == ConsoleKey.Backspace && passWord.Length > 0)
            {
                passWord = passWord.Substring(0, (passWord.Length - 1));
                Console.Write("\b \b");
            }

            if(CorrectLogin(userName, passWord))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\nValid Credentials! Press Enter to Continue");
                ConsoleKeyInfo enterKey = Console.ReadKey(true);
                if (enterKey.Key == ConsoleKey.Enter)
                {
                    Console.Clear();
                    switchMenu();
                }
            }                    
            else if (!(CorrectLogin(userName, passWord)))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\nInvalid Credentials... Press Enter to Retry");
                        passWord = "";
                        ConsoleKeyInfo enterKey = Console.ReadKey(true);
                        if(enterKey.Key == ConsoleKey.Enter){
                            Console.Clear();
                            mainMenu();
            }    
        }
        break;        
    } while (true);
}
```

Comment: You already know how to use `Console.WriteLine`. What keeps you from using it to output the lines right at the beginning of the `mainMenu` method?

Comment: @MarkusDeibel: my interpretation of the question is that they want to not just show the prompts, but have the user input adjacent to each prompt as well. I.e. a console/text-based form with data entry. See my answer below for an example of what I believe the OP is looking to accomplish.

Comment: @PeterDuniho I took the easy shot because of the stated requirement "[...] _multiple lines of text **before** user enters any input_ [...]". You went for the implied requirement I guess :)

Comment: @MarkusDeibel: immediately after the text you quote, there is also this: _"with the cursor next to username."_ To me, that indicates that it's not just writing the lines of text, but doing so in a way that allows the cursor to be placed next to the `"Username:"` prompt afterwards. Indeed, that's practically the literal thing the OP wrote. :)

Comment: @Mayora can you please add an example of what you want your final layout should look like _before_ the user inputs their `Username`? Also please mark the cursor position.

Comment: @MarkusDeibel it would be:      Username: (cursor here) then newline and Password: ... the same as how i put it in the original post

Comment: You also wrote " _only displays the password line once user input has been entered for username_ " which made me think 1) Everything is displayed top to bottom 2) `Password:` is not there as long as the username has not been entered. So why not display the text, then `Username:`, then wait for the input, then display `Password:` and here use your `do ... while` as it is.

Comment: @MarkusDeibel your quote of what i said is what currently happens. I also want it to display password from the start

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I got that wrong then and @PeterDuniho's answer seems about right ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the olden days, if we wanted to present the user with a form, a text screen was the only thing we even had. It involved repositioning the screen cursor as needed before each text element was drawn or user input was provided.

You can still do basically the same thing with a .NET console program, using the `Console.SetCursorPosition()` method. Here's a simple proof-of-concept demonstrating the basic idea:

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string promptFormat = "{0}: ";
    string[] fieldNames = { "Username", "Password" };
    string[] fieldPrompts = fieldNames.Select(s => string.Format(promptFormat, s)).ToArray();
    int columnWidth = fieldPrompts.Max(s => s.Length);

    Console.Clear();
    foreach (string prompt in fieldPrompts)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(prompt);
    }

    Dictionary<string, string> fieldValues = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    int line = 0;
    foreach (string field in fieldNames)
    {
        Console.SetCursorPosition(columnWidth, line++);
        string userValue = Console.ReadLine();
        fieldValues.Add(field, userValue);
    }

    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.WriteLine("You entered the following:");

    foreach (var kvp in fieldValues)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Field: \"{kvp.Key}\", Value: \"{kvp.Value}\"");
    }
}
```

You would of course need to adapt the user input routine for your password-style input. That level of detail is outside the scope of your actual question, so I didn't bother to include it in the above.

And naturally, you could just hard-code all the locations as well. In fact, that's often how it was done in the olden days too. The code to automatically lay out the user input position is just an easy little tweak to make the code a bit more general purpose. Hopefully you can see how you could include even more automatic-layout features, if you really wanted to.

Comment: I didn't know about Console.SetCursorPosition() -- that may come in handy one day.

Comment: thanks it ended up being a bit long winded but i just used Console.SetCursorPosition(); and set the positions based on the code i used to centre the text. Thanks so much